# PSD file convert into png format and apply watermark on formatted png file, But watermark's original colour is missing

Tags: php, imagemagick, rgb, watermark, composite

original file
[image]

Watermark img
[image]

After apply watermark
[image]

Code for PSD to PNG conversion:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert /tmp/1657736296-sample1.psd /tmp/sample1.png
```

Code for watermark apply on converted PNG file

```
/usr/local/bin/composite -limit memory 2GiB -gravity Center "/tmp/watermark_12809_1657825427.png" "1657825427-12788_109282907_1.png[0]" "1657825427-12788_109282907_1.png"
```

Comment: Please share your **actual** watermark image, rather than something composited onto a chessboard. Please ensure your question is **minimal**, we don't need to know the full paths to your **ImageMagick** binaries or to your images - they are not relevant here. Thank you.

Comment: So what is the question?  You have the code?  Does it not work? Post the original transparent watermark with transparency and without the checkerboard pattern!

Comment: I have a PSD file[https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zbae636mkkeikd/12788_109282907_1.psd?dl=0] and watermark as png[https://i.stack.imgur.com/51ETH.png] format or you can use any png file

Step 1: PSD file convert into PNG format: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZbJd.png]
Step 2: Apply the watermark into PNG format.
Step 3: watermark original colour missing after applying watermark [https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXqO5.png]

Comment: PSD to PNG conversion
/usr/local/bin/convert "/tmp/1657736296-sample1.psd" "/tmp/sample1.png"

Watermarked PNG
/usr/local/bin/composite  -gravity Center "/tmp/watermark.png" "/tmp/sample1.png[0]"  "/tmp/sample1.png"